# Looping issue with Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, foreach, key-value

I am looping a dictionary type and getting the issue, don't understand what am I doing wrong, did lots of search on google but :(

```
//Tour class have dictionary property of type <int, string>
public Dictionary<int, string> listTourCategoriesNames { get; set; }
```

On the front end i need to loop through on that property and fill into ListOfActivities list

```
public class TourActivitiesDB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

this.ListOfActivities = new List<TourActivitiesDB>();
foreach (var item in tourDB.listTourCategoriesNames)
{
    this.ListOfActivities.Add(new TourActivitiesDB { 
       ID = item.Key, //ERROR HERE
       Name = item.Value //ERROR HERE
    });
}
```

ERROR is:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have also used KeyValuePair instead of var in foreach loop but getting same issue. Thanks.

Attaching screenshot where you can see that im using the right type here with my dictionary:

[image]

Comment: Are you **SURE** it's a Dictionary<int, string>?

Comment: yes. i have also mentioned in my question on top. @ofstream

Comment: Can you tell us what tourDB.listTourCategoriesNames contains when it fails?

Comment: error is occurs while build.

Comment: Make sure you're looping over the right thing: Right Click on `tourDB.listTourCategoriesNames` within `foreach` loop and then "Go to definition". Is that really your dictionary shown?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes im sure, as i mentioned in my question too.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek         
public Dictionary<int, string> listTourCategoriesNames { get; set; }

Comment: move you mouse point onto the code `tourDB.listTourCategoriesNames` it will tell you what is the type of `listTourCategoriesNames`

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanSaleem It is clear that `tourDB.listTourCategoriesName` is **NOT** Dictionary. It is a `List<string>` , `string[]` ....

Comment: tourDB is an object of TOUR class and listTourCategoriesNames is property of that class which is of-course dictionary

Comment: @Turbot attached screen shot in question for ur reference.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek screenshot attached for ur reference

Comment: My guess is that Visual Studio has lost track of the types. I suggest you: 1. Clean the solution, 2. Rebuild the solution (and start using standard naming conventions (those upper and lowercases threw me off a couple of times)) If that doesn't help we need to see all of the code.

Comment: i did it, still unable to build. :( @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: Could you provide us with a download of the code?

Comment: unable to provide, its a huge animal. :) @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: Can you create a minimal version that has the same problem?

Comment: what is tour in your tour.listTourCategoriesName, namespace or class ?

agree with @Erno suggestion, clean the solution and rebuild using standard naming conventions will get a better view ?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd i have did the same thing with new class project in same project and its working fine. its mean there is some issue with my class project. :(

Comment: is there any reference that i missed here with my current project. @ErnodeWeerd

Comment: I repeat: it looks like Visual Studio has lost track of the correct types/assemblies/projects. If you used the Global Assembly Cache you might be running into an old version of the class project.

Comment: Do you get any other compilation errors, or just those two?

Comment: Please, provide Keys and Values list when you begin the foreach loop.

Comment: SOLVED!! Remove class library and add it again and everything working fine. :) So error is due to REFERENCE or VISUAL STUDIO.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and it seems to work as documented

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in dic)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} {kvp.Value}");
}
```